# Panel Admin The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5.8

hi i try to create panel admin but i have this error when i press submit (Updated Password) i have this error. If you think I problem it's in other file talk me

settings.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.adminLayout.admin_design')
@section('content')
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-header">
    <div id="breadcrumb"> <a href="index.html" title="Go to Home" class="tip-bottom"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home</a><a href="#" class="current">Settings</a> </div>
    <h1>Admin settings</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid"><hr>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
          <div class="widget-box">
            <div class="widget-title"> <span class="icon"> <i class="icon-info-sign"></i> </span>
              <h5>Update Password</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-content nopadding">
              <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" name="password_validate" id="password_validate" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Current Password</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="current_pwd" id="current_pwd" />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">New Password</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="new_pwd" id="new_pwd" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Confirm password</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_pwd" id="confirm_pwd" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                  <input type="submit" value="Update Password" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/welcome', 'PostController@postsabonnés')->name('posts.postsabonnes');

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@test');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.show');
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile/{user}', 'ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');

Route::get('/posts/create', 'PostController@create')->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store')->name('posts.store');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostController@show')->name('posts.show');
Route::get('/welcome', 'PostController@index')->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/', 'PostController@index')->name('posts.index');

Route::post('/follows/{profile}', 'FollowController@store')->name('follows.store');
Route::post('/search', 'PostController@search')->name('post.search');

    Route::middleware('ajax')->group(function () {
        Route::post('message', 'UserController@message')->name('message');
    });

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
    Route::get('/admin/settings', 'AdminController@settings');
});
Route::match(['get','post'], '/admin', 'AdminController@login');


Route::get('/logout', 'AdminController@logout');
```

AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Session;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->input();
            if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1'])) {
                Session::put('adminSession',$data['email']);
                return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
            }else{
                return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message_error', 'Invalid Username or Password');
            }
        }
        return view('admin.admin_login');
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        if(Session::has('adminSession'))
        {

        }else{
            return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message_error', 'Please login to access');
        }
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function settings()
    {
        return view('admin.settings');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message_success', 'Logged out Successfully');
    }
}
```

matrix_form_validation.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio],input[type=file]').uniform();

    $('select').select2();

    // Form Validation
    $("#basic_validate").validate({
        rules:{
            required:{
                required:true
            },
            email:{
                required:true,
                email: true
            },
            date:{
                required:true,
                date: true
            },
            url:{
                required:true,
                url: true
            }
        },
        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
    });

    $("#number_validate").validate({
        rules:{
            min:{
                required: true,
                min:10
            },
            max:{
                required:true,
                max:24
            },
            number:{
                required:true,
                number:true
            }
        },
        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
    });

    $("#password_validate").validate({
        rules:{
            current_pwd:{
                required: true,
                minlength:6,
                maxlength:20
            },
            new_pwd:{
                required: true,
                minlength:6,
                maxlength:20
            },
            confirm_pwd:{
                required:true,
                minlength:6,
                maxlength:20,
                equalTo:"#new_pwd"
            }
        },
        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

but i dont know where is the error because when try to change something error not move  someone can help me ? :/

Comment: What controller method handles updating passwords?

Comment: Currently the form is just posting to the current URL.

Comment: i have other file i add in edit post

Comment: what i can do for leave this error?

Comment: i press submit for see if password and other required